# How do I profile a Haskell program by CPU time?

Tags: haskell, profiling, ghc

I've got an interactive GHC program based on [GTK](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gi-gtk). One of the interactive functions is running strangely slowly and I'd like to profile it to find out why. However AFAICT GHC time profiling doesn't distinguish between a busy CPU and being suspended waiting for user input. Is it possible to tell GHC to only count actual CPU time instead of wall-clock time?

Comment: I don't know. But you're going to have a much better time if you set things up so that you can run your test without user interaction anyway (e.g. by mocking that interaction and supplying a fixed list of user inputs, if necessary). I bet you're going to want to run this experiment a lot of times; the more frictionless one run of the experiment is, the better your experience of fixing this thing will be.